# “Unregistered Git root detected” because parent directory of project is versioned by Git

Tags: git, intellij-idea, mercurial, pycharm

I set up a PyCharm project `/parent/project`, that is managed by Mercurial at `/parent/project/.hg`. Independently of this project, `/parent` is managed by Git at `/parent/.git`.

Unfortunately, this causes PyCharm to complain: "Unregistered Git root detected: The directory /parent is under Git, but is not registered in the Settings."

What's a clean solution for this?  Ideally, I would like PyCharm to simply ignore any repos in directories above the project directory itself.

Answer (score 0):

So far, IntelliJ supports only ignored files via http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-ignored-files.html. I'm afraid it won't help you with parent folder, though. You may want to separate VCS roots to unrelated folders in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In Intelij idea: You need to open Project Settings->Libraries and clear all red colored libraries which are not valid. 
click OK and error will disappear.